# Matlab surface plotting error for a specific function only

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, symbolic-math, surface

I have a small matlab script -

```
rho=1;
phi=0.5;
a=pi/4;
[x,y]=meshgrid(-1:1:1);
syms u;
Ex=abs(int(sqrt(cos(u))*exp(1i*rho*(cos(u-x.^2))),-a,a));
surf(x,y,Ex);
```

This throws the error

> Error using matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.Surface/set
>
> Invalid parameter/value pair arguments.

But there shouldn't be as `Ex` is a 3x3 matrix, so is the grid. Surface plotting should proceed smoothly.

But if I define a function that doesn't use the `int()` function, for example -

```
z=x.^2+y.^2;
surf(x,y,z);
```

Then there is no error.

Does it has something to do with `syms` variables?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why *are* you using a symbolic variable here? How do you expect `surf` to evaluate that against the `x` and `y` coordinates you've supplied?

Comment: I thought that for every point on the grid, the function would be integrated using the symbolic variable and matrix Ex would be updated. Matlab documentation uses syms, so I decided to use them.

Comment: The MATLAB documentation does *not* use syms, it explicitly says `Z` (the 3rd input) should be a matrix? I'm also now not sure what integration you expect `surf` (a plotting function) to do here? Evaluate `Ex` first, then plot - you can probably do this without symbolic variables.

Comment: I'm already specifying the limits of integration, so there is no value to substitute for using subs() function. I tried it but still the same problem.

Comment: Try plotting `double(Ex)` instead of `Ex`.

Comment: Yess.. this works.. thanks. problem was that Ex contained symbolic expressions. Using double(Ex) evaluates them.